# If the sum of two independent random variables is in $L^2$, is it true that both of them are in $L^1$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, lp-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables. If $\mathbb E(X+Y)^2 < \infty$, do we have $\mathbb E |X| < \infty$ and $\mathbb E |Y| < \infty$?

What I actually want is that $X$ and $Y$ are both in $L^2$, i.e., $\mathbb E X^2 < \infty$ and $\mathbb E Y^2 < \infty$. But this can be reduced to $\mathbb E |X|\mathbb E |X| < \infty$. Thus it suffices to show that $X$ and $Y$ are in $L^1$.

It might be helpful to see that since $|X| < |Y| + |X+Y|$, (and by symmetry), either both of $X$ and $Y$ or none of them are in $L^1$. So we may assume $\mathbb E |X| = \infty$ and $\mathbb E |Y| = \infty$ and try to find a contradiction. But here is where I got stuck.

Comment: A general fact is that if $X \in L^p$ then $X \in L^q$ for all $q<p$. 

This is easy to prove: $E[|X|^q] = E[|X|^q I(|X|>1) + |X|^q I(|X|\leq 1) ] = E[|X|^q I(|X|>1)]+ E[ |X|^q I(|X|\leq 1) ] \leq E[|X|^p I(|X|>1)] + E[ 1 I(|X| \leq 1) \leq E[|X|^p] + P(|X| \leq 1) \leq E[|X|^p] +1 < \infty $.

Comment: @Batman That's why proving $X$ and $Y$ are in $L^1$ should be an easier task, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that 
$$\mathbb E(X+Y)^2=\int_{\mathbb R^2}(x+y)^2\mathrm d\mathbb P_X\otimes \mathbb P_Y(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}(x+y)^2 \mathrm d \mathbb P_X(x)\right)\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y)=\\=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb E[(X+y)^2]\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y).$$
Since $y\mapsto \mathbb E[(X+y)^2]$ is integrable over $\mathbb R$ for some probability measure, it's in particular finite for some $y$, hence $\mathbb E(X^2)$ is finite. Similarly, one can show that $\mathbb E(Y^2)$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

If they have the finite mean x=$E X < \infty$  and $y= E Y <\infty$ then yes 
$E(X+Y)^2 = E(X^2)+E(Y^2)+2 E(X)*E(Y) = E(X^2)+E(Y^2)+2xy < \infty$. If no, I am affraid one can found a pathological case  when this is not true.

Let me update myself. I think the previous answer given by David Giraudo is correct. Let me just a little expand it. $E(X+y)^2<\infty$ for some $y$ means 
that $E(X+y)=E(X)+y<\infty$ for this $y$. This means that $E(X)<\infty$. This means that   $E(X+y)^2=E(X^2)+2E(X)y+y^2 <\infty$. So $E(X^2)<\infty$.

Comment: Can you give an example s.t. $\mathbb E(X+Y)^2 < \infty$ but $\mathbb E X = \infty$ and $\mathbb E Y = \infty$?

Comment: But assuming they have finite mean is assuming they are in $L^1$, which is the whole point.

Comment: No, a variable may have zero (finite mean) but not $L^1$ .

Comment: $X$ may have large negative values, $Y$ large positive numbers, both may have not finite mean and sum be ok. Even if they are independent.

Comment: "a variable may have zero (finite mean) but not L1" This is not true. You might want to check your lecture notes on the subject.

Comment: OK. How about this example. Take a variable $a$ that is not $L^1$. Namely $E(|a|)$ is infinity. Define a variable that with prob 0.5 is $a$ and with prob 0.5 $-a$. Then $E(|x|)$  is infinity and $E(x)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I don't have a right to do this. You are right.